# Can't preview images in lf file manager with iterm2 under macOS

Tags: configuration, config, iterm2, file-manager

I installed the `lf` file manager on macOS and configured it for my purposes but I can't configure it for image preview.

I tried it using `ueberzugpp` but it needs to add `lfrun` file to /usr/bin. It's not possible because it wants to remove system integrity protection.

I tried the `w3mimgdisplay` method described in `lf` github wiki. It also failed, but I can use `imgcat` to show images in `iterm2`.

Can I implement it to show images in `lf` file manager?

The `ranger` wiki page has `iterm2` integration directly for image preview. It works in my `ranger`. But I want to use `lf` because I can run shell script in it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Start by configuring [`lf`](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf) preview as explained in the man page by creating a `~/.config/lf/lfrc` file:

```
set previewer ~/.config/lf/pv.sh
map i $~/.config/lf/pv.sh $f | less -R
```

and creating the `~/.config/lf/pv.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    *.tar*) tar tf "$1";;
    *.zip) unzip -l "$1";;
    *.rar) unrar l "$1";;
    *.7z) 7z l "$1";;
    *.pdf) pdftotext "$1" -;;
    ) highlight -O ansi "$1";;
esac
```

Set the script as executable with:

```
chmod +x ~/.config/lf/pv.sh
```

`lf` preview is now configured as in the man page. To add image preview, you can modify `~/.config/lf/lfrc` such as:

```
set previewer ~/.config/lf/pv.sh
map i $~/.config/lf/pv.sh $f
```

and `~/.config/lf/pv.sh` such as:

```
#!/bin/sh

alias imgcat=/Users/von/.iterm2/imgcat
case "$1" in
    *.tar*) tar tf "$1" | less -R;;
    *.zip) unzip -l "$1" | less -R;;
    *.rar) unrar l "$1" | less -R;;
    *.7z) 7z l "$1" | less -R;;
    *.pdf) pdftotext "$1" - | less -R;;
    *.jpg|*.jpeg) imgcat "$1" && read -n 1 -s -r;;
    *) highlight -O ansi "$1" | less -R;;
esac
```

This will allow you to preview jpeg files by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> in `lf`. You can easily add another image file formats in the preview script.

The main difference with the example in documentation is that the pager (`less -R`) is run directly in the preview script and only for text formats, as the pager cannot be run on images.